# Strange Behavior by Recruiters on LinkedIn

Tags: recruitment, linkedin, behavior, psychology

I wanted to talk about something strange that's been happening with me and recruiters on LinkedIn.

The thing is, the recruiters contact me there through the messaging service describing a potential role, asking when I would be available to discuss more, and to reply with my resume. And they're all marked as recruiters by LinkedIn.

So I reply with my resume (and I have a regularly updated one present already on my profile on the front page) saying that I'm grateful they reached out to me about the role and I would be delighted to discuss more, etc.

The strange thing is, after explicitly and directly reaching out to me to get in touch, not a single one of the recruiter ever replies back when I reply to their original message. And I don't even take that long to reply, usually a few hours.

Can someone please help me to figure out what might be going on? What am I doing wrong? Why does every recruiter turn cold without exception? I have no criminal history or anything. What could be the cause?

How should I handle this?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @MichaelMcFarlane, thank  you for replying. Could you please elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @StackMatch Sorry, disregard it. I was being a smart ass, but in a slightly encouraging way.

Comment: Thank you to everyone. Reading these responses gives me a better understanding of the situation. I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Recruiters are frequently just spammers**

They send out a hundred messages, see what resumes they collect, and then see where they can shop them. The roles may or may not exist. You could be completely unqualified for them. They don't care as it is all a numbers game to them.

I keep getting everything from Business Intelligence to Purchasing jobs. I have never worked in either and my last 3 positions I have explicitly been a software engineer and in the one before that, I was also a software engineer in practice (if you read the job description).

It doesn't stop the spam. Nothing does. Most will never reply. Don't take much from it.

Comment: I still get recruiters sending me exciting opportunities about desktop technician positions (something I haven't done in more than 20 years).

Comment: @JoelEtherton you at least did that job. My last LinkedIn message was about being a QA Analyst, a job I have never done.

Comment: Thank you for replying Mr. Gaiser. Your advice certainly helps me feel much better. Thank you for clarifying about what might be going on. It seems just so puzzling to me that recruiters reach out to me using my name, specifically quoting details about my profile and asking me to reply. I would say they definitely know what I'm qualified for as the jobs are always matched to my skills and experience. It's just so strange and disheartening to see it happen so many times. Are the recruiters playing idle games with people? I had hoped I would have found at least one exception so far.

Comment: Oh I have a bunch as well for financial analyst, sales rep, the list goes on. Vetting a recruiter has become a new job hunting skill.

Comment: My whole Linkedin experience has been 100% spam and I don't even have a picture or work history in it or anything except my name

Comment: It definitely seems true that most or perhaps even all the unsolicited linked-in recruiter contacts seem to be just copy/pasting a few facts from my profile and listing some vaguely related (possibly non existent) job opportunity, sometimes not even in the area where I currently live.  When I set my profile to 'actively looking for work'  I got a lot more real interest and not just resume-collector spam.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check their LinkedIn profile and they are a real recruiters? From my recruitment experience their is an internal recruitment cycle not only the recruiters are the responsible one  their is other employees inside the company review your profile my they have some concerns it doesn't mean you are not qualified but it means not match 100% for example you didn't work on a product like the company product ,etc....
But the professional recruiter attitude will feedback you. Unfortunately maybe they are working on a mass hiring and they didn't give you a feedback.

Comment: Thank you Ms. Shakshak. Your answer gives me another useful insight.

Comment: Yikes, can you give this answer a good proofread and clean up the grammar? I can't even figure out what you're trying to say.